# How to add interactive pins on images in flutter?

Tags: image, mapping, flutter, interactive, pins

I have trouble integrating images with interactive pins on Flutter.is it even possible? if so, how can I do it? Im looking for something similar to WordPress's Image Mapper plugin!

Comment: So you want pins that can be moved by the user?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.The pins will be used to identify objects in a photo.For example a clothing e-commerce app where an image of a outfit could have pins for each clothing item.The pin displaying a price of the clothing item and has an onTap callback adding the item to a cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Stack` widget is what you want:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    <your image>,
    Positioned(
      left: 50.0,
      top: 30.0,
      child: <your pin>
    ),
    ...
  ],
)
```